# Resampling by day and category a DataFrame that have datetime start and datetime end

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, resampling, rolling-computation

### Question

Given a table (DataFrame) of events, where each event (row) has its datetime of start and datetime of stop and the category of event.

How can I transform this table into a table where each row is a combination of all days and categories with the associated hours on this day for this category of event?

### Example

Maybe it's easier to see an example than explain the problem:

I want to transform this DataFrame

| datetime_start | datetime_end | event_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:30:00 | 2021-01-03 16:30:00 | 'A' |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | 2021-01-01 15:30:00 | 'B' |
| 2021-01-01 22:00:00 | 2021-01-01 23:00:00 | 'B' |

Into this DataFrame

| date | event_category | sum_of_hours_with_event_active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 'A' | 13.5 |
| 2021-01-01 | 'B' | 7.5 |
| 2021-01-02 | 'A' | 24 |
| 2021-01-02 | 'B' | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 'A' | 16.5 |
| 2021-01-03 | 'B' | 0 |

Comment: It can get very complicated if you can have overlapping timespans on the same day for the same event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain there are no overlapping time periods on the same day within the same event category (or you want to double count those time periods) then you can create the basis of all dates by event categories and merge your timespans onto that DataFrame.

Then by subtracting with clipping we can calculate the total time that event contributes for that day only (resulting negative values don't correspond to that day so they get clipped to 0). Finally, we can `sum` within day by event.

```
import pandas as pd

# Enumerate all categories for every day. 
dfb = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'event_category': df['event_category'].unique()}),
               pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(df.datetime_start.dt.normalize().min(),
                                                   df.datetime_end.dt.normalize().max(), freq='D')}),
               how='cross')

# Merge timespans 
m = dfb.merge(df, on='event_category')

# Calculate time for that day
m['sum_hours'] = ((m['datetime_end'].clip(upper=m['date']+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1))
                   - m['datetime_start'].clip(lower=m['date']))
                   .clip(lower=pd.Timedelta(0)))

# Sum of hours for event by day
m = (m.groupby(['event_category', 'date'])['sum_hours']
      .sum().dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
      .reset_index())
```

---

```
print(m)
  event_category       date  sum_hours
0              A 2021-01-01       13.5
1              A 2021-01-02       24.0
2              A 2021-01-03       16.5
3              B 2021-01-01        7.5
4              B 2021-01-02        0.0
5              B 2021-01-03        0.0
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar. I really appreciated date_range instead of my list-comprehension and the merge with how='cross' instead oh my numpy.meshgrid

Answer (score 1):

#### Data

```py
import pandas as pd

start_times = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01 10:30:00', '2021-01-01 09:00:00', '2021-01-01 22:00:00'])
end_times = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-03 16:30:00', '2021-01-01 15:30:00', '2021-01-01 23:00:00'])
categories = ['A', 'B', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_start': start_times, 'datetime_end': end_times, 'event_category': categories})
```

#### Answer

First we `groupby` event_category so that the `apply` works per category.  The concatenation of the two series represents the changes in the events, that is, the beginnings and ends of events.  The `groupby` and `sum` inside the `apply` are needed in case there are multiple events which start or end at the same time in the same category.  The cumulative sum (`cumsum`) gives the total number of events at the times that there were changes, that is, at the times when one or more event started or ended.  Next we upsample with `asfreq` to the desired frequency.  This should be at least equal to the time granularity of the data.  Finally we resample again (implemented with `groupby` and `Grouper` objects) and `sum`.

Essentially we are counting the number of periods occupied by all the events in each category and multiplying by the length of a period (half hour in the example) and then grouping by day.  The `DateOffset` object is used to parametrize the period.

```py
step = pd.DateOffset(hours=0.5)  # Half hour steps
df.groupby('event_category') \
  .apply(lambda x: pd.concat([pd.Series(1, x['datetime_start']),
                              pd.Series(-1, x['datetime_end'])]) \
         .groupby(level=0) \
         .sum() \
         .cumsum() \
         .asfreq(step, method='ffill')
        ) \
  .groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), pd.Grouper(level=1, freq='D')]) \
  .sum() * step.hours
```

This will work for overlapping events in the same category.

### Results

```
event_category
A               2021-01-01    13.5
                2021-01-02    24.0
                2021-01-03    16.5
B               2021-01-01     7.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Asssuming datetime start and end are 0.5 hours discrete is not correct. I put them like this just for simplicity

Comment: Unfortunately also apply method becomes unefficient with many rows

Comment: @user11696358 You can change the `hours` parameter of the `DateOffset` object to match the underlying data.  For example `1/60` for up to the minute or `1/3600` for up to the second granularity.  This would reduce performance even further.